# Check if list contains an Id/String in Visualforce

Tags: apex, visualforce

Is there a way I can put a condition in rendered attribute to check if a List contains an Id/String or not in Visualforce page?

I tried this but its not working or somehow I am doing something wrong:

```
rendered="{!IF( CONTAINS( '{!employees}', '{!Id/String}' ), true, false ) }"
```

Thanks

Comment: I posted this question after looking all possible solutions including one you suggested @TusharSharma

Comment: This question is indeed a duplicate of that question; the solution mentioned should serve you well.

Comment: Indeed the other post was helpful and with that I was able to fix above code but I had to modify/tweak the code a bit to make it work which I was asking help for. Thank all for you inputs.